# Add typescript file in VS2013

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013

There is no item in context menu in the solution explorer to add an typescript file to the project?

The only possibility seems to be to add it via `file->new` and then adding it as an existing file to the project. Unfortunately the `.js`and `.min.js` are not added as dependencies to the project then.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was because I had installed the TypeScript Visual Studio extension before I had upgraded to Visual Studio 2013.

If you install the [Visual Studio extension](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) again (select the "Repair" option) it will detect you now have Visual Studio 2013 and fix your issue.

Comment: If you right-click the project and select `Add` -> `New Item`, can you find it if you type into the search in the top right of the add dialog? If so, once you add your first TypeScript file to the project it should become a short-cut and solve your build issue.

Comment: there is no typescript file in the `add new item` dialog

Comment: That's very strange. I know this will sound annoying, but it may be worth uninstalling the Visual Studio extension entirely and then re-installing it.

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar issue, I had to go to "Add" -> "New Item..." and search for TypeScript, after I had added a TypeScript file the context menu appeared correctly.

Also I had to download the latest version of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

From VS , Do new Project, scroll down the list of templates you should see Typescript, in the right hand pane select install the latest Typescript for visual studio, reboot, restart VS whatever ! and enjoy the goodness from the creator of c#